# SQL: Dynamic Join Based on Row Value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**Context:**
I am working with some complicated schema and have got many CTEs and joins to get to this point. This is a watered-down version and completely different source data and example to illustrate my point (data anonymity). Hopefully it provides enough of a snapshot.

**Data Overview:**
I have a service which generates a production forecast looking ahead 30 days. The forecast is generated for each facility, for each shift (morning/afternoon). Each forecast produced covers all shifts (morning/afternoon/evening) so they share a common `generation_id` but different `forecast_profile_key`.

**What I am trying to do:** I want to find the SUM of the forecast error for a given forecast generation constrained by a dynamic date range based on whether the date is a weekday or weekend. The SUM must be grouped only on similar IDs.

Basically, the temp table provides one record per facility per date per shift with the forecast error. I want to SUM the historical error dynamically for a facility/shift/date based on whether the date is weekday/weekend, and only SUM the error where the IDs match up.. (hope that makes sense!!)

**Specifics:** I want to find the SUM grouped by `'week_part_grouping'`, `'forecast_profile_key'`, `'forecast_profile'` and `'forecast_generation_id'`. The part I am struggling with is that I only want to SUM the error dynamically based on date: (a) if the date is a weekday, I want to SUM the error from up to the 5 recent-most days in a 7 day look back period, or (b) if the date is a weekend, I want to SUM the error from up to the 3 recent-most days in a 16 day look back period.

Ideally, having an extra column for 'total_forecast_error_in_lookback_range'.

**Specific examples:**

- For `'facility_a'`, `'2020-11-22'` is a weekend. The lookback range is 16 days, so any date between '2020-11-21' and '2020-11-05' is eligible. The 3 recent-most dates would be '2020-11-21', '2020-11-15' and '2020-11'14'. Therefore, the sum of error would be 2000+3250+1050.
- For `'facility_a'`, `'2020-11-20'` is a weekday. The lookback range is 7 days, so any date between '2020-11-19 and '2020-11-13'. That would work out to be '2020-11-19':'2020-11-16' and '2020-11-13'.
- For `'facility_b'`, notice there is a change in the 'forecast_generation_id'. So, the error for '2020-11-20' would be only be 4565.

**What I have tried:** I'll confess to not being quite sure how to break down this portion. I did consider a case statement on the week_part but then got into a nested mess. I considered using a RANK windowed function but I didn't make much progress as was unsure how to implement the dynamic lookback component. I then also thought about doing some LISTAGG to get all the dates and do a REGEXP wildcard lookup but that would be very slow..

I am seeking pointers how to go about achieving this in SQL. I don't know if I am missing something from my toolkit here to go about breaking this down into something I can implement.

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS seventh__error_calc;

create temporary table seventh__error_calc
(
facility_name varchar,
shift varchar,
date_actuals date,
week_part_grouping varchar,
forecast_profile_key varchar,
forecast_profile_id varchar,
forecast_generation_id varchar,
count_dates_in_forecast bigint,
forecast_error bigint
);

Insert into seventh__error_calc

VALUES

('facility_a','morning','2020-11-22','weekend','facility_a_morning_Sat_Sun','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','1000'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-21','weekend','facility_a_morning_Sat_Sun','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','2000'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-20','weekday','facility_a_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','3000'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-19','weekday','facility_a_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','2500'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-18','weekday','facility_a_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','1200'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-17','weekday','facility_a_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','5000'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-16','weekday','facility_a_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','4400'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-15','weekend','facility_a_morning_Sat_Sun','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','3250'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-14','weekend','facility_a_morning_Sat_Sun','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','1050'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-13','weekday','facility_a_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','2450'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-12','weekday','facility_a_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','2450'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-11','weekday','facility_a_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','2450'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-10','weekday','facility_a_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','2450'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-09','weekday','facility_a_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','2450'), 
('facility_a','morning','2020-11-08','weekend','facility_a_morning_Sat_Sun','Profile#facility_a#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','2450'), 

('facility_b','morning','2020-11-22','weekend','facility_b_morning_Sat_Sun','Profile#facility_b#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','3400'), 
('facility_b','morning','2020-11-21','weekend','facility_b_morning_Sat_Sun','Profile#facility_b#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','2800'), 
('facility_b','morning','2020-11-20','weekday','facility_b_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_b#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','3687'), 
('facility_b','morning','2020-11-19','weekday','facility_b_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_b#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','6809dea6','8','4565'), 
('facility_b','morning','2020-11-18','weekday','facility_b_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_b#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','7252fzw5','8','1262'), 
('facility_b','morning','2020-11-17','weekday','facility_b_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_b#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','7252fzw5','8','8765'), 
('facility_b','morning','2020-11-16','weekday','facility_b_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_b#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','7252fzw5','8','5678'), 
('facility_b','morning','2020-11-15','weekend','facility_b_morning_Mon_Fri','Profile#facility_b#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','7252fzw5','8','2893'), 
('facility_b','morning','2020-11-14','weekend','facility_b_morning_Sat_Sun','Profile#facility_b#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','7252fzw5','8','1928'), 
('facility_b','morning','2020-11-13','weekday','facility_b_morning_Sat_Sun','Profile#facility_b#dfc3989b#b6e5386a','7252fzw5','8','4736')
;
    
SELECT *
FROM seventh__error_calc
```

Comment: The SQL - Is this to generate the table? and we have to apply the dynamic join on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

This achieved what I was trying to do. There were two learning points here.

1. Self Joins. I've never used one before but can now see why they are powerful!
2. Using a CASE statement in the WHERE clause.

Hope this might help someone else some day!

```
select  facility_name,
        forecast_profile_key,
        forecast_profile_id,
        shift,
        date_actuals,
        week_part_grouping,
        forecast_generation_id,
        sum(forecast_error) forecast_err_calc
from (
    select  rank() over (partition by forecast_profile_id, forecast_profile_key, facility_name, a.date_actuals order by b.date_actuals desc) rnk,
            a.facility_name, a.forecast_profile_key, a.forecast_profile_id, a.shift, a.date_actuals, a.week_part_grouping, a.forecast_generation_id, b.forecast_error
    from    seventh__error_calc a
    join    seventh__error_calc b
    using   (facility_name, forecast_profile_key, forecast_profile_id, week_part_grouping, forecast_generation_id)
 
    where case when a.week_part_grouping = 'weekend' then b.date_actuals between a.date_actuals - 16 and a.date_actuals
               when a.week_part_grouping = 'weekday' then b.date_actuals between a.date_actuals - 7 and a.date_actuals
               end
    ) src
where case when week_part_grouping = 'weekend' then rnk < 4
           when week_part_grouping = 'weekday' then rnk < 6
           end
```